# show VR tour in android

Tags: android

I want to show VR tour like this http://alfavr.ir/alfavr.ir/to/park.html in my Android app.
how can I do that?
I tried to display with web view because the file format is Html but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this line make It work.

```
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with VRPanormaView which is included in the Google VR SDK. This is an example from https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/android/vrview:

```
<com.google.vr.sdk.widgets.pano.VrPanoramaView
    android:id="@+id/pano_view"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="@null"
    android:layout_height="250dip" />
```

Inside the Activity, the primary method is `VrPanoramaView.loadImageFromBitmap()`. Call it with a standard Android Bitmap object and an optional `VrPanoramaView.Options` object. The latter is used to configure the format of the image. The Activity also implements a `VrPanoramaEventListener` which receives events when the load operation succeeds or fails.